# Handling short reads using epoll()

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, epoll

Let's say client sent 100 bytes of data but somehow server only received 90 bytes. How do I handle this case? If server calls the "read" function inside of while loop checking the total received data then the server will wait forever for the pack last 10 bytes..

Also, it could happen that client got disconnected in the middle of data transfer. In this case also server will wait forever until it receives all the data which won't arrive..

I am using tcp but in real world network environment, this situation could happen. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call the `read()` function in a loop until you receieve the number of bytes you require.  Instead, you set the socket to nonblocking and call the `read()` function in a loop until it returns `0` (indicating end of stream) or an error.

In the normal case the loop will terminate by `read()` returning -1, with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`.  This indicates that the connection hasn't been closed, but no more data is available at the current time.  At this point, if you do not have enough data from the client yet, you simply save the data that you *do* have for later, and return to the main `epoll()` loop.

If and when the remainder of the data arrives, the socket will be returned as readable by `epoll()`, you will `read()` the rest of the data, retreieve the saved data and process it all.

This means that you need space in your per-socket data structure to store the read-but-not-processed-yet data.

Answer (score 1):

You must carefully check the return value of `read`.  It can return any of *three* things:

A positive number, indicating some bytes were read.

Zero, indicating the other end has gracefully closed the connection.

-1, meaning an error occurred.  (If the socket is non-blocking, then the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK means the connection is still open but no data is ready for you right now, so you need to wait until `epoll` says there is more data for you.)

If your code is not checking for each of these three things and handling them differently, then it is almost certainly broken.

These cover all of the cases you are asking about, like a client sending 90 bytes then closing or rudely breaking the connection (because read() will return 0 or -1 for those cases).

If you are worried that a client might send 90 bytes and then never send any more, and never close the connection, then you have to implement your own timeouts.  For that your best bet is non-blocking sockets and putting a timeout on select() / poll() / epoll(), ditching the connection if it is idle for too long.

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection is a bi-directional stream layered on top of packet-based network. It's a common occurrence to read only part of what the other side sent. You have to read in a loop, appending until you have a complete message. For that you need an application level protocol - types, structure, and semantics of messages - that you use on top of TCP (FTP, HTTP, SMTP, etc. are such protocols).

To answer the specific second part of the question - add [`EPOLLRDHUP`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) to the set of [`epoll(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) events to get notified when connection drops.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what caf has said, I'd recommend just subscribing EPOLLRDHUP because this is the only safe way to figure out whether a connection was closed (read() == 0 is not reliable as, caf mentioned this too, may be true in case of an error). EPOLLERR is *always* subscribed to, even if you didn't specifically asked for it. The correct behaviour is to close the connection using close() in case of EPOLLRDHUP and probably even when EPOLLERR is set.

For more information, I've given a similar answer here: [epoll_wait() receives socket closed twice (read()/recv() returns 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724137/epoll-wait-receives-socket-closed-twice-read-recv-returns-0/6762385#6762385)